# How to convert Alphanumeric Values to value ranges in Typescript?

Tags: arrays, typescript, range

```
myArray = ["AB01","AB02","AB03","AB04","AB11","BC12","BC13", "SB33"];

// expected string "AB01-AB04, AB11, BC12-BC13, SB33"
```

The letters can be one or two characters. Digits can be two or three characters.
Ex: A001, A002, AB001, AB002, AC01, AC02, B01, B02.

Only these formats are possible.

How to achieve this in a simplified manner?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: Are the prefixes always going to be 2 letters?

Comment: I was writing this question's answer, but the question was locked, so i update the question with answer. Hope it helps you.

Comment: @VahidAlimohamadi I have edited the question. It has been unlocked. You can post your answer now. Thank You.

Comment: They closed this !!!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/g71m0epf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let myArray = ["AB01","AB05","ABCDEFG01123","ABCDEFG01124","AB02","AB03","AB04","AB11","BC12","BC13", "SB33"];

function getRanges(array, group) {
  var ranges = [], rstart, rend;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    rstart = array[i];
    rend = rstart;
    while (array[i + 1] - array[i] == 1) {
      rend = array[i + 1];
      i++;
    }
    ranges.push(rstart == rend ? group+rstart+'' : group+rstart + '-' + group+rend);
  }
  return ranges;
}

// group first.
let groups = myArray.reduce((groups,item)=>{
  let belongsTo = item.match(/[a-zA-Z]/g).join('');
  groups[belongsTo] ? groups[belongsTo].push(item) :groups[belongsTo]=[item];
  return groups;
},{})

let expectedString = Object.entries(groups).reduce((output,[key,value])=>{
  output=`${output}${output.length ? ', ' : ''}${getRanges(value.map(i=>i.match(/[0-9]/g).join('')),key)}`;
  return output;
},'');

console.log(expectedString);
// expected string "AB01-AB04, AB11, BC12-BC13, SB33"
```